# Docker unable to configure as systemd service

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Docker unable to configure as Service.

Post installing docker, none of the docker commands are responding, like docker info or docker version.

Installed docker ce and its components from package.

```
sudo dpkg -i containerd.io_1.2.4-1
             docker-ce_18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
             docker-ce-cli_18.09.9~3-0~ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb
```

Followed by

```
sudo systemctl enable docker.service
sudo systemctl enable containerd.service
```

docker.service is under /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

```
BindsTo=containerd.service
After=network-online.target firewalld.service containerd.service
Wants=network-online.target
Requires=docker.socket

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon $DOCKER_OPTS -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
TimeoutSec=0
RestartSec=2
Restart=always
StartLimitBurst=3
StartLimitInterval=60s

LimitNOFILE=1048576
LimitNPROC=1048576
LimitCORE=1048576

TasksMax=infinity
Delegate=yes
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/default/docker content:

```
export http_proxy="http://proxy.com:80/"
export https_proxy="http://proxy.com:80/"
export NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1,.example.com"
export no_proxy=$NO_PROXY

DOCKER_OPTS="--dns <dns server> --dns <dns server> -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4321 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver=devicemapper --storage-opt dm.datadev=/dev/vg-docker/data  
--storage-opt dm.metadatadev=/dev/vg-docker/metadata --storage-opt dm.basesize=100G"
```

On checking the status, it just hangs with below message

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Mon 2021-04-26 08:48:55 PDT; 2min 2s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 21021 (docker)
    Tasks: 17
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─21021 /usr/bin/docker daemon --dns 171.40.110.110 --dns 171.40.110.111 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:4321 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock --storage-driver=devicemapper -

 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
```

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04**

Comment: Or you can install Ubuntu's provided package: docker.io which is even more recent than this one (on x86): https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/docker.io

Comment: [suggestions for troubleshooting](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/).